# How to render and view Un-Formatted Json source code of a website in a web browser for a full web page without any HTML or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, json

Basically at work we are trying to speed up our website search results page and I wrote some unit tests to test the webpage automatically in JavaScript (Json) now I want to get the specific element IDs that I want to test for from the webpage source code so how do I get the webpage to display raw data without XML or anything? which I can then format and read using plugins such as Json viewer for chrome. The lead developer quickly showed me a way where he typed something in the URL bar of the web browser along with the URL and the webpage rendered and the entire webpage went into white background with black un-formatted lines of code so how do I do that?

Comment: *The lead developer quickly showed me a way where he typed something in the URL bar of the web browser along with the URL* ... you mean something like `view-source:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58355828/how-to-render-and-view-un-formatted-json-source-code-of-a-website-in-a-web-brows` - of course if you're on a webpage, you just hit `ctrl-u` to show that

Comment: Is it a Ruby on Rails backend? Maybe he just replaced `https://someurl.com/foo.html` with `https://someurl.com/foo.json`?

Comment: well it was something like what Bravo had mentioned above but I have been hitting ctrl U and nothing happens on any website. also I am on a Mac, will I don't think he changed anything to json at the end of the URL